# How does BIOS or Grub loader utilize the GPU?

Tags: bios, gpu

How is the GPU utilized by BIOS, Grub loader or any "Pre-OS" activity?

I think I have a GPU overheat issue that leads to system shutdown. The problem happens, if I stay in BIOS, Grub loader and Boot menu for more than 30 seconds. However, if the system manages to load into Linux, it can stay up for several days as long as I don't overload the GPU.

Does this mean that the BIOS and other Pre-OS activities utilize the GPU more than the OS itself? If yes, I don't understand how would a blue and white screen utilize the GPU more than a fully functional desktop environment.

BIOS A04,

GPU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]

Dell Inspiron N5010

Comment: GPU model, MoBo model, BIOS version?

Comment: It might be that the fan control is not activated properly by the `POST`

Comment: The fan is running at full speed, heat sink is clean and thermal paste is applied @Serge

Comment: hmm, then it sounds strange.

Comment: Yes very, I am willing to give up the computer just to know a logical explanation for the problem. Haha!!